# Python: What is an elegant idiom for extending method with one or more keyword arguments?

Tags: python

I'm trying to extend a method with a single keyword argument while remaining impartial to the rest of the method's signature; I just want to pass that on. Attempt 0:

```
class SomeSuperclass(object):
    pass # in reality: some implementation for some_method

class SomeClass(SomeSuperclass):
    def some_method(self, my_kwarg=42, *args, **kwargs):
        super(SomeClass, self).some_method(*args, **kwargs)
        do_something_interesting_with(my_kwarg)

SomeClass().some_method('arg 0', 'arg 1', some_kwargs=5, my_kwarg=8)
```

This does not work:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 9, in <module>
    SomeClass().some_method('arg 0', 'arg 1', some_kwargs=5, my_kwarg=8)
TypeError: some_method() got multiple values for keyword argument 'my_kwarg'
```

I fully understand why the above does not work, but I'm looking for a nice way to make it work. This is my current (ugly) workaround:

```
class SomeClass(SomeSuperclass):
    def some_method(self, *args, **kwargs):
        my_kwarg = kwargs.get('my_kwarg', 42) 
        if 'my_kwarg' in kwargs:
            del kwargs['my_kwarg']
        super(SomeClass, self).some_method(*args, **kwargs)
        do_something_interesting_with(my_kwarg)
```

That's 3 lines of cruft per kwarg...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd use [`dict.pop()`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dict.pop), like so:

```
class SomeSuperclass(object):
  def some_method(self, *args, **kwargs):
    print 'SomeSuperclass: args=%s kwargs=%s' % (args, kwargs)

class SomeClass(SomeSuperclass):
  def some_method(self, *args, **kwargs):
    my_kwarg = kwargs.pop('my_kwarg', 42) # 42 is the default
    print 'SomeClass: my_kwarg=%s' % my_kwarg
    super(SomeClass, self).some_method(*args, **kwargs)

SomeClass().some_method('arg 0', 'arg 1', some_kwargs=5, my_kwarg=8)
SomeClass().some_method('arg 0', 'arg 1', some_kwargs=5)
```

When run, this prints out:

```
SomeClass: my_kwarg=8
SomeSuperclass: args=('arg 0', 'arg 1') kwargs={'some_kwargs': 5}
SomeClass: my_kwarg=42
SomeSuperclass: args=('arg 0', 'arg 1') kwargs={'some_kwargs': 5}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `{}.pop()` to turn your 3 lines of cruft into 1:

```
my_kwarg = kwargs.pop('my_kwarg', 42)
```

Comment: I think this works too: my_kwarg = kwargs.pop('my_kwarg', 42)